# Jhipster, spring, angular jar working but not war working

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, jhipster, war

I created spring + angular + gradle with Jhipster.

I first do

`npm install`

Then , I run this command:

```
./gradlew -Pprod -Pwar clean bootWar
```

which reads gradle/war.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "war"

bootWar {
    mainClassName = "com.bpn.legolas.ExtractAccountApp"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]
    webXml = file("${project.rootDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml")
}

war {
    webAppDirName = "build/resources/main/static/"
    webXml = file("${project.rootDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml")
    enabled = true
    archiveExtension = "war.original"
    includes = ["WEB-INF/**", "META-INF/**"]

}
```

and it creates a war. But when i deploy to another machine, to tomcat, i got the error page:

> An error has occured :-( Usual error causes You started the
>   application from an IDE and you didn't run npm start or npm run
>   webpack:build. You had a network error while running npm install. If
>   you are behind a corporate proxy, it is likely that this error was
>   caused by your proxy. Have a look at the JHipster error logs, you will
>   probably have the cause of the error. You installed a Node.js version
>   that doesn't work with JHipster: please use an LTS (long-term support)
>   version, as it's the only version we support. Building the client side
>   code again If you want to go fast, run ./mvnw to build and run
>   everything.
>
> If you want to have more control, so you can debug your issue more
>   easily, you should follow the following steps:
>
> Install npm dependencies with the command npm install Build the client
>   with the command npm run webpack:build or npm start Start the server
>   with ./mvnw or using your IDE Getting more help If you have a question
>   on how to use JHipster Go to Stack Overflow with the "jhipster" tag.
>
> If you have a bug or a feature request First read our contributing
>   guidelines.
>
> Then, fill a ticket on our bug tracker, we'll be happy to resolve your
>   issue!
>
> If you want to chat with contributors and other users Join our chat
>   room on Gitter.im. Please note that this is a public chat room, and
>   that we expect you to respect other people and write in a correct
>   English language!

For same steps, i export as jar.

First

```
npm install
```

Then

```
./gradlew -Pprod -Pjar clean bootJar
```

Than at that machine, i do

```
java -jar xxxx.jar
```

and it works! But for war, as i said before, it does not work. It says about `npm install or`webpack`

Please help me about it.

**STEPS**
1- My war name is **halil-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war**
2- I put to webapps under `tomcat`
3- Then i go to:

http://localhost:8080/halil-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

4- I see the errors which i put in the screenshot.[image: error in the page]
Which i posted as text in this question
5- Javascript console shows those errors:
[image: error in the console]
6- Network shows those errors:
[image: errror in the network tab]
7- When i go to
http://localhost:8080/halil
or
http://localhost:8080/

it brings 404 page

Comment: Have you unzipped the war file to check that angular app bundle is present?  Which url do you use in browser to get the error page? What is the name of your war in tomcat?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou war name is halil-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war . localhost:8080/halil-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is url. and i checked inside and they are bunled

Comment: @GaëlMarziou i put war under webapp files. It is autodeploying. And i opened localhost:8080/halil-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and it showed error about `An error has occured :-( Usual error causes You started the application from an IDE and you didn't run npm start or npm run webpack:build.`

Comment: The error is useless in this context, it is useful mostly in dev, it has nothing to do with npm. Have you tried renaming your war as `halil.war` without version and accessing `http://localhost:8080/halil/`with a trailing slash?

Comment: You can change the version in your `pom.xml` between `<version>` tags. See if that helps, otherwise we might need more info in order to help you (javascript errors in your console?).

Comment: @vicpermir i use **gradle** not **maven** :( 
@GaëlMarziou i also tried to go to `/halil` but it is same. I also renamed to `root.war` but nothing changed

Comment: Woops, you are right sorry. Have you checked for JS errors in your browser console?

Comment: @vicpermir i added to end of the question

Comment: Hi! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to migrate from Angular 4 to Angular 12 in my Jhipster project.

The issue was that the static folder was not being created before creating the war:

- gradle script was wrong (the npm build was running in the correct step before the war)

So I have solved it following these steps:

- Run `npm build`, so the static folder was created (you must be sure the exact path for your static folder is correct)
- Check if the static folder was created in the path your war is expecting
- Run `./gradlew -Pprod -Pwar clean bootWar`

Comment: This approach helped me to create the war file using the following command `./mvnw -Pprod -Pwar clean install`